# Mysql: insert a new row in a child table with new values except for foreign key column which is obtained from parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I'm having this situation. i want to insert a new row into a table which has a foreign key constraint to another table. when i insert a new row, i have new values obtained from user input except for the foreign key column which is to be obtained from the parent table. and the foreign key is an auto_increment primary key in the parent table. here is a the minimized schema to illustrate, only the relevant columns are shown.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  CUSTOMER_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      .
  .
  .


  PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE)
);

CREATE TABLE BOOKING (  
  BOOKING_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CUSTOMER_CODE INTEGER NOT NULL,
  BOOKING_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  .
  .
  .

  PRIMARY KEY (RESERVATION_CODE),
  CONSTRAINT BOOKING_CUSTOMER_FK FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER   
                                                                        (CUSTOMER_CODE)
);
```

i want to know the insert statement that will feed into the BOOKING table a new row with values generated based on user interaction with the system for the rest of the columns (like `booking_date`) but obtain the `customer_code` from the customer table with a `where email=` clause with an email obtained from user input.

Comment: In a broader context your application would have some login facility where you would have been asking him for login credentials. Just save those credentials in the session. After that you can query database for the id of the user having xyz unique email. Now you are having all the values. Go ahead with it. Insert the record.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya that's what i'm asking for...the syntax of the insert statement

Comment: insert into booking values(....,12,....). 12 here is the customer id taken from the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine 2 statements you can use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    BOOKING
    (CUSTOMER_CODE, BOOKING_DATE)
SELECT
    CUSTOMER_CODE, $booking_date
FROM
    CUSTOMER
WHERE
    CUSTOMER.email=$email
```

You put your values into SELECT as hard-coded and fetch CUSTOMER_CODE for the appropriate email. But make sure, that you are protected from SQL injection.

Comment: this is what i am doing. but i was wondering if there is a way i can use one statement. i am using JDBC with connector j but i'm getting exceptions but when i do it on the CLI using msql.exe it works ok.

Comment: how can i combine the two statements?

Comment: How to achieve the same using spring data jpa

Comment: @TusharBanne I think, you'd better ask a separate question using a Java tag.